# How to text align the text in 2nd row with text in 1st row in tablet (md) view

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

.row {

 width: 100%;
}

.section-title1, .section-title2, .section-title3  {
 position: absolute;
 width: 60px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-title1 {
 background-color: red;
}

.section-title2 {
 background-color: cyan;
}

.section-title3 {
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3 {
 position: relative;
 text-align: justify;
 width:90%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 25px;
}

.section1 {
 background-color: pink;
}

.section2 {
 background-color: green;
}

.section3 {
 background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
 margin:  20px;
 text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

 .col-lg-4 {

  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;

 }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

 .col-md-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .col-md-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .col-sm-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black; 
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Module 2 assignment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Our menu </h1>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p class="section1"><span class="section-title1">Chicken</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p class="section2"><span class="section-title2">Beef</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><p class="section3"><span class="section-title3">Sushi</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need ideas on text aligning the text in 2nd row with text in 1st row in tablet (md) view.

Here is the problem screenshot:[image: See how the text in second line is not aligned with text in line 1]

Comment: so to clarify, you want spacing above the paragraph in the green container that puts Lorem Ipsum at the same horizontal level as "print and typesetting..." in the pink box?

Comment: @JosephPerez I want to edge align the text in yellow box with the text in pink box and green box. Makes sense ?

Comment: ooooh hold up. lemme edit my answer demo

Comment: okay so this is super trippy. you have two ways. either make the yellow div take up a width of calc(100% - 4 * some certain margin you have on the pink and green divs, which is hard because you gave them auto margins. the other thing you could do is give the yellow div a width of 100% and set the entire grid layout to contain everything inside a certain width only when that min-width: 768px and max-width: 991px is used...

Comment: The problem with your code is margins, I adjusted those, try my code, may be this will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace with my styles...! then it works fine, everything okay with your code except css.

```
.section1, .section2, .section3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

.row {

 width: 100%;
}

.section-title1, .section-title2, .section-title3  {
 position: absolute;
 width: 60px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-title1 {
 background-color: red;
}

.section-title2 {
 background-color: cyan;
}

.section-title3 {
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}

.section1 {
 background-color: pink;
}

.section2 {
 background-color: green;
}

.section3 {
 background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
 margin:  20px;
 text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

 .col-lg-4 {

  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;

 }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

 .col-md-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .col-md-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .col-sm-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black; 
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Module 2 assignment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<style>
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}

.row {

 width: 100%;
}

.section-title1, .section-title2, .section-title3  {
 position: absolute;
 width: 60px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

.section-title1 {
 background-color: red;
}

.section-title2 {
 background-color: cyan;
}

.section-title3 {
 background-color: lightblue;
}

.section1, .section2, .section3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}

.section1 {
 background-color: pink;
}

.section2 {
 background-color: green;
}

.section3 {
 background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
 margin:  20px;
 text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

 .col-lg-4 {

  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;

 }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

 .col-md-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .col-md-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .col-sm-12 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black; 
 }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Our menu </h1>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p class="section1"><span class="section-title1">Chicken</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p></div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"><p class="section2"><span class="section-title2">Beef</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p></div>
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"><p class="section3"><span class="section-title3">Sushi</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the margin. I was letting margin-left and margin-right to be auto on the p elements. But the bigger problem was I setting width to be 90%.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you want. Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/jpezninjo/pen/bWyxXO

I placed a new span around your content and gave it

```
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 16px;
```

on @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)

Answer (score 0):

Here throw this inside @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
Demo: https://codepen.io/jpezninjo/pen/bWyxXO

```
 .section1, .section2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 2 * 15px);
  }

  .section3 {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: calc(100% - 2 * 15px)
  }
```

I went with the first approach I mentioned above. Here we have fixed margins and calculated widths that stretch your 3 sections to line up perfectly.